# Windows Filtering Platform: ClassifyFn BSOD at DISPATCH_LEVEL

Tags: c, windows, driver, windows-kernel, wfp

I'm trying to implement a simple firewall which filters network connections made by Windows processes.

The firewall should either allow/block the connection.

In order to intercept connections by any process, I created a kernel driver which makes use of [Windows Filtering Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page).

I registered a [ClassifyFn (FWPS_CALLOUT_CLASSIFY_FN1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fwpsk/nc-fwpsk-fwps_callout_classify_fn1) callback at the filtering layer FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4:

```
FWPM_CALLOUT m_callout = { 0 };
m_callout.applicableLayer = FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4;
...
status = FwpmCalloutAdd(filter_engine_handle, &m_callout, NULL, NULL);
```

The decision regarding connection allow/block should be taken by userlevel.

I communicate with Userlevel using [FltSendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltsendmessage), 
which cannot be used at IRQL DISPATCH_LEVEL.

Following the instructions of the Microsoft documentation regarding how to [process callouts asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/processing-classify-callouts-asynchronously), 
I do call [FwpsPendOperation0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fwpsk/nf-fwpsk-fwpspendoperation0) before calling FltSendMessage.

After the call to FltSendMessage, I resume packet processing by calling [FwpsCompleteOperation0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fwpsk/nf-fwpsk-fwpscompleteoperation0?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

FwpsPendOperation0 documentation states that calling this function should make possible to operate calls at PASSIVE_LEVEL:

> A callout can pend the current processing operation on a packet when
>   the callout must perform processing on one of these layers that may
>   take a long interval to complete or that should occur at IRQL =
>   PASSIVE_LEVEL if the current IRQL > PASSIVE_LEVEL.

However, **when the ClassifyFn callback is called at DISPATCH_LEVEL, I do sometimes still get a BSOD on FltSendMessage (INVALID_PROCESS_ATTACH_ATTEMPT)**.

I don't understand what's wrong.

Thank you in advance for any advice which could point me to the right direction.

Here is the relevant code of the ClassifyFn callback:

```
/*************************
ClassifyFn Function
**************************/
void example_classify(
    const FWPS_INCOMING_VALUES * inFixedValues,
    const FWPS_INCOMING_METADATA_VALUES * inMetaValues,
    void * layerData,
    const void * classifyContext,
    const FWPS_FILTER * filter,
    UINT64 flowContext,
    FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT * classifyOut)
{

    NTSTATUS status;
    BOOLEAN bIsReauthorize = FALSE;
    BOOLEAN SafeToOpen = TRUE; // Value returned by userlevel which signals to allow/deny packet
    classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_PERMIT;

    remote_address = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS].value.uint32;
    remote_port = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4_IP_REMOTE_PORT].value.uint16;

    bIsReauthorize = IsAleReauthorize(inFixedValues);
    if (!bIsReauthorize)
    {
        // First time receiving packet (not a reauthorized packet)
        // Communicate with userlevel asynchronously

        HANDLE hCompletion;
        status = FwpsPendOperation0(inMetaValues->completionHandle, &hCompletion);

        //
        // FltSendMessage call here
        // ERROR HERE:
        // INVALID_PROCESS_ATTACH_ATTEMP BSOD on FltMessage call when at IRQL DISPATCH_LEVEL
        //

        FwpsCompleteOperation0(hCompletion, NULL);
    }

    if (!SafeToOpen) {
        // Packet blocked
        classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_BLOCK;
    }
    else {
        // Packet allowed
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke FltSendMessage() on another thread running at PASSIVE_LEVEL.  You can use IoQueueWorkItem() or implement your own mechanism to process it on a system worker thread created via PsCreateSystemThread().